# Table format: shifted \cmidrule and column extra space

Tags: tables, formatting

I have the following script using IEEE conference template from: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/?lang=en

I find formatting this table tricky. The problems are:

1) The most left column is not right. I need the black horizontal lines to start from the beginning of the row (see some space in the left of each row) and I need one space before starting the text of the row (need it to look similar to the most right column).

2) Column `A` must be underlined like column `B` and `C`. But, the line is not well placed. It should end before the vertical line.

Here is the script:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\title{Test Document}

% make the title area
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction.

\begin{table*}[tb!] 
\caption{A Table}

\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular} {@{} lc*{16}l @{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} 
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{B}    
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{C}  
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{D}  
&&\multicolumn{2}{c}{E}  

\\
\cmidrule(lr){0-1} 
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} 
\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
\cmidrule(lr){11-13}
\cmidrule(lr){15-16}
\\
& \vline &\rot{Col. 1} & \rot{Col. 2} & \rot{Col. 3} 
& \vline & \rot{Col. 1} & \rot{Col. 2} & \rot{Col. 3} 
& \vline & \rot{Col. 1} & \rot{Col. 2} &\rot{Col. 3} 
& \vline & \rot{Col. 1} & \rot{Col. 2} 

\\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
Text1 &\vline  & \cmark & {}     & {}     & \vline  & {}     & \cmark  & {}      & \vline  & {} &\cmark  & & \vline &    & \cmark \\\hline
Text2 &\vline  & {}     & \cmark & {}     & \vline  & {}     & \cmark   & {}      & \vline & {} & \cmark & & \vline & {} & \cmark   \\\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text3 & \vline & \cmark & {}     & {}     & \vline  & {}     & \cmark   & {}      & \vline & {} &\cmark  & &\vline & {} & \cmark    \\
\hline
Text4 & \vline & \cmark & {}    & {}     & \vline   & {}     & \cmark   & {}      & \vline & {} &\cmark  & &\vline & {} & \cmark   \\
 \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
Text5 & \vline & {}     & \cmark & {}    & \vline   & \cmark  & {}      & {}      & \vline & \cmark & {} & &\vline & {} & \cmark    \\
\hline
Text6 & \vline & \cmark & {}    & {}     & \vline   & \cmark  & {}      & {}      & \vline & {}     & \cmark & & \vline & {} & \cmark   \\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text7 & \vline & \cmark & {}    & {}     & \vline   & \cmark  & {}      & {}       & \vline & \cmark & {}    & & \vline & \cmark & {}  \\
\hline
Text8 & \vline & \cmark & {}   & {}     & \vline    & {}     & \cmark   & {}      & \vline  & {}     &\cmark & & \vline & {} & \cmark  \\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text9 & \vline & {}     & {}     & \cmark & \vline & \cmark  & \cmark  & {}       & \vline  & {}     &\cmark & & \vline & {} & \cmark \\\hline
Text10 & \vline & {}     & {}     & \cmark & \vline & {}      & {}      & \cmark   & \vline  & {}     &\cmark & &\vline & {} & \cmark   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by using `@{}` in `tabular` column definition. work around is explained in documentation of `colortbl` package, so it has nothing with used document class.

**Edit:**
In case, that you will consider to use `tabularx` instead of `tabular`, the solution of your problem is:

- reduce number of columns to number of columns with content (12)
- change column definition to (with out vertical lines)

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l
                                                                 *{10}{C}
                                >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}C
                            @{}}
```

or (with vertical lines)

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l  |
                                                                  *{3}{CCC|}
                                                                       C 
                                >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}C
                            @{}}
```

**Off-topic:**
I took liberty in change your table so, that it can fit in column width. For this I use `tabularx` table environment, reduce font size to `\small`, remove vertical lines and for horizontal lines use rules from `booktabs` (to obtain more professional look of table):

[image]

As you can see, this table hasn't your problems. Maybe you liked it :). The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% instead of colortbl
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}% added
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{A Table}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Col. 3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l
                                                                 *{10}{C} 
                                >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}C
                            @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}       
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}   
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{C}
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{D}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{E}           \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
\cmidrule(lr){11-12}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2} & \rothead{Col. 3}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2} & \rothead{Col. 3}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2} & \rothead{Col. 3}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2}                   \\ 
    \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text1   & \cmark        &               & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text2   &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        & \cmark        &               & \cmark        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text3   & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &  
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text4   & \cmark        &               & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text5   &               & \cmark        &
        & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\hline
Text6   & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text7   & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &                               \\
Text8   & \cmark        &               & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text9   &               &               & \cmark 
        & \cmark        & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text10  &               &               & \cmark 
        &               &               & \cmark   
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Above MWe should work also with `IEEEtran` document class (which now I haven't installed).

If you persist to have table over two columns and with vertical lines, than replace in above MWE consider instead existing the following lines:

```
...
    \begin{table*}
\caption{A Table}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Col. 3}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l  |
                                                                      *{3}{CCC|}
                                                                           C
                                    >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}C
                                @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}       
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}   
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{C}
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{D}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{E}           \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
\cmidrule(lr){11-12}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2} & {Col. 3}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2} & {Col. 3}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2} & {Col. 3}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2}                   \\ 
    \hline
    ...
```

and you will obtain:

[image]

Edid (2):
and with all vertical lines as in code in your question and with vertical column heads:

[image]

complete MWE for the last image is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% instead of colortbl
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}% added
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table*}
\caption{A Table}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Col. 3}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}l|
                                                                      *{3}{CCC|}
                                                                           C
                                    >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}C
                                @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}       
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}   
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{C}
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{D}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{E}           \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
\cmidrule(lr){11-12}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2} & \rothead{Col. 3}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2} & \rothead{Col. 3}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2} & \rothead{Col. 3}
        & \rothead{Col. 1} & \rothead{Col. 2}                   \\ 
    \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text1   & \cmark        &               & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text2   &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        & \cmark        &               & \cmark        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text3   & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &  
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text4   & \cmark        &               & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text5   &               & \cmark        &
        & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text6   & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text7   & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &               & 
        & \cmark        &                               \\
Text8   & \cmark        &               & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text9   &               &               & \cmark 
        & \cmark        & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text10  &               &               & \cmark 
        &               &               & \cmark   
        &               & \cmark        & 
        &               & \cmark                        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Edit (3):**
And for fun and completeness *off-topic* sugestions one more solution without (black) vertical lines, without rotating column headers and all columns have equal width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% instead of colortbl
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table*}
\caption{A Table}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}X   @{\quad}
                                                                      *{3}{CCC @{\quad}}
                                                                           C
                                    >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}C
                                @{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{C}
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{D}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{E}           \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(r){5-7}\cmidrule(r){8-10}
\cmidrule{11-12}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2} & {Col. 3}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2} & {Col. 3}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2} & {Col. 3}
        & {Col. 1} & {Col. 2}                   \\
    \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text1   & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text2   &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        &
        & \cmark        &               & \cmark        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text3   & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text4   & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text5   &               & \cmark        &
        & \cmark        &               &
        & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text6   & \cmark        &               &
        & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text7   & \cmark        &               &
        & \cmark        &               &
        & \cmark        &               &
        & \cmark        &                               \\
Text8   & \cmark        &               &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9}
Text9   &               &               & \cmark
        & \cmark        & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
Text10  &               &               & \cmark
        &               &               & \cmark
        &               & \cmark        &
        &               & \cmark                        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

All above off-topic suggestions consider your wish to color rows. I personally will not color rows. For help reader to track rows I would eventually add some vertical space after each forth rows in try to fit table into one column. However, different people, different taste, ...

Comment: @user6875880, see edited answer.

Comment: And what is benefit, that it is vertical when it can be horizontal? To make it vertical again: just return `\rothead`. Added in again (this time last) edited answer

Comment: @user6875880, and what then? Are you not capable add yourself? At least this can be exercise for you, isn't it?

Comment: @user6875880 Your comments sound like "make it all for me" instead of "tell me how I can make it". Please be aware that we mostly prefer the last.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry for that. I just thought the answer should be for what the question exactly asked so I can accept it and it becomes reference for others.

Comment: @user6875880, I not intend to argue with you even you haven't right. Let me only emphasize: my answer has two parts: in the first is answer on what you exactly ask, in the second part, title with **off-topic**, I give some suggestion (for which you not ask), how to improve your table. So, if you not liked, you are not obligated to consider as I'm not obligated to follows to your complains, that your table is different, even if if they obviously contain typing error (missing vertical lines, now corrected).

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use `tabularx`  and no `\resizebox`. The vertical rules are put as separators between columns, so I have only 12  columns. Also, I took the liberty to change the look of the rotated column heads,: a rotation of 40°, so their height is smaller:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot[1][90]{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\myrot[1]{\rotatebox[origin=l]{40}{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\title{Test Document}

% make the title area
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction.


\begin{table*}[!htb]
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}\centering
  \caption{A Table}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth} { l|*{3}{CCC|}*{2}{C}|@{}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{A}
           & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B}
           & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C}
           & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D}
           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E}
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
    \cmidrule(lr){11-12}
           & \myrot{Col. 1} & \myrot{Col. 2} & \myrot{Col. 3}
           & \myrot{Col. 1} & \myrot{Col. 2} & \myrot{Col. 3}
           & \myrot{Col. 1} & \myrot{Col. 2} & \myrot{Col. 3}
           & \myrot{Col. 1} & \myrot{Col. 2}
    \\ \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}Text1
           & \cmark & & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\\hline
    Text2 & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\\hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    Text3 & \cmark & & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
    Text4 & \cmark & & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    Text5 & {} & \cmark & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
    Text6 & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    Text7 & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & \\
    \hline
    Text8 & \cmark & & & & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    Text9 & & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
    Text10 & & \cmark & & & & \cmark & & \cmark & & & \cmark \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a rotation of 90°, replace in  the table body`\myrot` with `\rot` to obtain this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But such columns text does not fit my need. I need it vertical as I posted.

Comment: @user6875880: Just replace `\myrot` with `\rot`. Please see the updated answer.